# Hardtime implementing tool tip in span tag

Tags: css, tooltip

I am new to this community so bear with me if there are any mistakes in question formatting.

I am trying to implement tool tip as shown in image, i have tried the following snippet:

```html
    <span class="animationTabularFilterSettingsRectangle" id="animationTabularFilterSettingsRectangle">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);"id="settings"><i class="gt-settings"></i></a>
                                <span class="settingsArrow"></span>
                                </span>
```

css for tool tip:

```css
     width: 283px;
      height: 523px;
      border: solid 1px #cccccc;
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Required Tool tip view]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly. (F.e. _“css for tool tip”_ gives us no idea what element you are actually applying this two, and the shown HTML does not make it obvious either, which element is supposed to be the actual tooltip element.) Also, explain what specifically you are struggling with.

Comment: Please add the display:block; and u will get the structure.. plz explain clearly

Comment: Hey, because it's only CSS and HTML, you can always try to make a working snippet. This way people can see the problem and adjust your code to make it work :)

Comment: Hi @Manikandan2811, thanks for the reply, the `css` that has been written is for class `settingsArrow`. I want that css over there in orientation as shown in image.